# How to convert String Json to Json in java

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jpa

I am trying to convert a String Json result i got from querying a postgres jsonb column from a spring boot application,

Here is what the result i am getting look likes

```
  [
     "[\n    {\n        \"exam\": 50.0,\n        \"grade\": \"A\",\n        
     \"total\": 79.0,\n        \"position\": \"First\",\n        
     \"student_id\": \"89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144\",\n        
     \"assessment_1\": 9.0,\n        \"assessment_2\": 17.0,\n        
     \"assessment_3\": 5.0,\n        \"student_name\": \"Anana 
     Aristotle\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"exam\": 50.0,\n        
     \"grade\": \"A\",\n        \"total\": 79.0,\n        
     \"position\": \"First\",\n        \"student_id\": \"89f36efe- 
     1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144\",\n        \"assessment_1\": 
     9.0,\n        \"assessment_2\": 17.0,\n        
     \"assessment_3\": 5.0,\n        \"student_name\": \"Anana 
     Aristotle\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"exam\": 50.0,\n        
     \"grade\": \"A\",\n        \"total\": 79.0,\n        
     \"position\": \"First\",\n        \"student_id\": \"89f36efe- 
     1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144\",\n        \"assessment_1\": 
     9.0,\n        \"assessment_2\": 17.0,\n        
    \"assessment_3\": 5.0,\n        \"student_name\": \"Anana 
    Aristotle\"\n    },\n    {\n        \"exam\": 50.0,\n        
    \"grade\": \"A\",\n        \"total\": 79.0,\n        
    \"position\": \"First\",\n        \"student_id\": \"89f36efe- 
    1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144\",\n        \"assessment_1\": 9.0,\n        
    \"assessment_2\": 17.0,\n        \"assessment_3\": 5.0,\n        
    \"student_name\": \"Anana Aristotle\"\n    }\n]"
  ]
```

I have already try to do this in my service before returning the result, still i can get the expected result:

```
    public List<?> getStudentAssessments(){
    List<?> assessments = 
       assessmentRepository.getStudentAssessments();
       Gson gson = new Gson();

       return  Collections.singletonList(gson.toJson(assessments));
    }
```

Here are the codes i am working with:

My Repository

```
@Query(value = "select jsonb_pretty(a.assessment) from assessment a 
where subject_id = 8", nativeQuery = true)
List<?> findAssessmentsByGrade();
```

My Service

```
public List<?> getStudentAssessments(){

    return assessmentRepository.getStudentAssessments();

}
```

And my controller

```
@ResponseBody
@GetMapping("")
public List<?> getForms(){

    return assessmentService.getStudentAssessments();

}
```

Here is my expected result:

```
[
   {"exam": 50.0, "grade": "A", "total": 79.0, "position": "First", 
   "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144"}, 
   {"exam": 50.0, "grade": "A", "total": 79.0, "position": "First", 
   "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144"},
]
```

Without the newline.

Comment: You can use Jackson framework from Json String to Java object easily.

Answer (score 2):

You have JSON text in a Java String that starts with a `[` and have string literals:

```
[ "..." ]
```

So parse that as JSON into a `String[]` or `List<String>`.

In this case, there is 1 value in the array, so get it. That string value is another JSON text:

```
[
    {
        "exam": 50.0,
        "grade": "A",
        "total": 79.0,
        "position": "First",
        "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144",
        "assessment_1": 9.0,
        "assessment_2": 17.0,
        "assessment_3": 5.0,
        "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
    },
    {
        "exam": 50.0,
        "grade": "A",
        "total": 79.0,
        "position": "First",
        "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144",
        "assessment_1":9.0,
        "assessment_2": 17.0,
        "assessment_3": 5.0,
        "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
    },
    {
        "exam": 50.0,
        "grade": "A",
        "total": 79.0,
        "position": "First",
        "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144",
        "assessment_1":9.0,
        "assessment_2": 17.0,
        "assessment_3": 5.0,
        "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
    },
    {
        "exam": 50.0,
        "grade": "A",
        "total": 79.0,
        "position": "First",
        "student_id": "89f36efe-1f36-48dc-92bc-c33df2784144",
        "assessment_1": 9.0,
        "assessment_2": 17.0,
        "assessment_3": 5.0,
        "student_name": "Anana Aristotle"
    }
]
```

Assuming you have a `StudentAssessment` class that matches those objects, parse it into a `StudentAssessment[]` or `List<StudentAssessment>`.

In short, you need to **call the JSON parser twice**.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to use Jackson for this.

Here is how it would be done by me:

> 1) Create your data transfer object

```
public class AssessmentDto {
    private Double exam;
    private String grade;
    private Double total;
    private String position;

    @JsonProperty("student_id")
    private UUID studentId;

    // Getter & Setters omitted for brevity
}
```

> 2) Write deserialization logic

```
private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

public List<?> getStudentAssessments(){
    List<?> assessments =
            assessmentRepository.getStudentAssessments();


    return  assessments.stream()
            .map(a -> readAssessment(a))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}

private Object readAssessment(Object a) {
    try {
        return mapper.readValue(a.toString(), new TypeReference<List<AssessmentDto>>() {});
    } catch (JsonParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```